# Calculate Average Duration from a Series of Dates

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Well, I have one collection with too much documents(millions), and now i wanna know how I can calculate average of session duration.

This is a example of structure of my docs:

```
{
    "session" : "xyz",
    "date" : {"$date" : ""Tue May 15 2018 10:35:08 GMT-0400 LT""}
}
{
    "session" : "xyz",
    "date" : {"$date" : ""Tue May 15 2018 12:35:08 GMT-0400 LT""}
}
{
    "session" : "xyz",
    "date" : {"$date" : ""Tue May 15 2018 15:35:08 GMT-0400 LT""}
}
{
    "session" : "abc",
    "date" : {"$date" : ""Tue May 15 2018 09:35:08 GMT-0400 LT""}
}
{
    "session" : "abc",
    "date" : {"$date" : ""Tue May 15 2018 11:35:08 GMT-0400 LT""}
}
```

And I wanna define a algorithm like this:

1. Get all documents by "$session"
2. Calculate min(first) date and max(last) date of these(2nd point) documents.
3. Calculate duration(time difference) by session
4. Repat first 1st point with another "$session"
5. after calculate all average by "$session", calculate average of these total.

I think first need using `aggregate` with $group, but I dont have experience with that and now I have a existencial problem hahaha

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as "sequence" is not important here then [`$min`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/) and [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) are the right things:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$session",
    "minDate": { "$min": "$date" },
    "maxDate": { "$max": "$date" }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "avg": {
      "$avg": { "$subtract": [ "$maxDate", "$minDate" ] }
    }
  }}
])
```

The initial [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) obtains the [`$min`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/) and [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) values from the "grouping key" provided which is the `"session"` value in the document. The the second [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) is done without any grouping key ( or `null` ) in order to accumulate "everything".

When you [`$subtract`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) one BSON Date from the other, then the result is the difference in milliseconds. This is also a handing way of casting to a numeric value in general. But all you do is [`$subtract`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) the two values output from [`$min`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/) and [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) and feed that to the [`$avg`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/substrBytes/) accumulator.

Comment: Well, I resolve it with "$first" and "$last", but it work fine :D  thanks too much

Comment: @OlafErlandsen Sure that's find. Just remember that `$first` and `$last` occur in the "order of discovery". Typically you really should `$sort` before using those operators, and the point of `$min` and `$max` is where you don't have to. If you are interested in "more than **one** value" however, then `$sort` and those operators is usually what you actually require. You just asked for one, so the operators here are more efficient and reliable for that case.